# How to convert hash in array to array in ruby

Tags: ruby

I have array that element is hash

```
a = [{:history_date=>"15/07/10"}, {:open_price=>"7.90"}]
```

I want to convert to this

```
h = {:history_date=>"15/07/10", :open_price=>"7.90"}
```

someone please help me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about:

```
h = a.inject(&:merge)
```

Each hash in the array is merged into the previous hash until we get down to one element. `&:merge` is shorthand for the following, which may be easier to understand, but is slightly longer:

```
h = a.inject { |all, element| all.merge(element) }
```